# Application that opened is still Desktop Chrome responsive, it is not mobile responsive view

Tags: ionic-framework, cypress

```
describe('Production Test Suite', function(){
  it('TC02_AuthorizedLoginVerification_Mobile', function()
  {
    cy.viewport('samsung-s10')
    cy.visit('https://www.google.com')
  })
})
```

I tried running above code, the view looks like mobile layout but the application thats opened is still
desktop view, it is not mobile responsive view

Here is the screenshot that might help you understand the issue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you have to override the userAgent in request headers using your [cypress.json](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Browser) file. User-agent values are typically used by servers to help identify the operating system, browser, and browser version.

1.To find the relevant user agent for your use-case, you can go to developer tools of your chrome browser and then browse to Network Conditions.

[image: Chrome Network Conditions]

2.In the Network Conditions, select your relevant device and copy the user-agent value:

[image: List of available browsers]

[image: user-agent values]

3.In your cypress.json, override the userAgent value as:

```
"userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Pixel 4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

4.Execute your test:

```
it('TC02_AuthorizedLoginVerification_Mobile', function() {
  cy.viewport('samsung-s10')
  cy.visit('https://www.google.com')
})
```

[image: Cypress Execution]

Answer (score 0):

The problem with google's search page is it has a css `min-width` property set to `400px` on one of the outer elements,

```html
<div class="ctr-p" id="viewport" data-hveid="1">

.ctr-p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

so a device set to `360px` wide will not be properly responsive below this min-width.

You can observe it by opening google in a browser, open the dev tools and manually resize the panes. The page is responsive only down to the `400px` point.

You can also run this

```js
cy.visit('https://www.google.com')
const widths = [600, 550, 500, 450, 400, 350 ];
widths.forEach(width => {
  cy.viewport(width, 700)
})
```

then hover over the Cypress log entries and observe the snapshots doing the same thing (responsive, except for the last setting).

---

You can **scale** the page if desired, for example the following widths are all responsive (at 50% scaling)

```js
cy.visit('https://www.google.com')
cy.get('body').invoke('css', 'zoom', '50%')

const widths = [600, 550, 500, 450, 400, 350, 300, 250, 200 ];
widths.forEach(width => {
  cy.viewport(width, 700)
})
```